# Compiling simpleVRML project on ARToolkit

Tags: c++, artoolkit

I was compiling the artoolkit libraries so I can use it on my project. All 28 projects on the artoolkit (http://sourceforge.net/projects/artoolkit/files/artoolkit/2.72.1/) can be compiled but I'm having a problem compiling the simpleVRML project which uses the openVRML library (which is also in the same link) it always have an error that looks like this:

Error   225 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl std::operator==,class std::allocator >(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,char const *)" (__imp_??$?8DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@PBD@Z) referenced in function __ehhandler$??0sentry@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE@AAV12@@Z   C:\Users\John Paulo\Documents\Photorealistic Rendering\Prototype\MK-1.1.2\examples\simpleVRML\antlr.lib(Parser.obj)
Error   226 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl std::operator==,class std::allocator >(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,char const *)" (__imp_??$?8DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@PBD@Z)  C:\Users\John Paulo\Documents\Photorealistic Rendering\Prototype\MK-1.1.2\examples\simpleVRML\openvrml.lib(browser.obj)
Error   227 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl std::operator==,class std::allocator >(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,char const *)" (__imp_??$?8DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@PBD@Z)  C:\Users\John Paulo\Documents\Photorealistic Rendering\Prototype\MK-1.1.2\examples\simpleVRML\openvrml.lib(script.obj)
Error   228 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl std::operator==,class std::allocator >(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,char const *)" (__imp_??$?8DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@PBD@Z)  C:\Users\John Paulo\Documents\Photorealistic Rendering\Prototype\MK-1.1.2\examples\simpleVRML\openvrml.lib(vrml97node.obj)
Error   229 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl std::operator==,class std::allocator >(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,char const *)" (__imp_??$?8DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@PBD@Z)  C:\Users\John Paulo\Documents\Photorealistic Rendering\Prototype\MK-1.1.2\examples\simpleVRML\openvrml.lib(doc.obj)
Error   230 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl std::operator==,class std::allocator >(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &)" (__imp_??$?8DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@0@Z) C:\Users\John Paulo\Documents\Photorealistic Rendering\Prototype\MK-1.1.2\examples\simpleVRML\openvrml.lib(doc.obj)
Error   231 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl std::operator==,class std::allocator >(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &)" (__imp_??$?8DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@0@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall antlr::BaseAST::BaseAST(void)" (??0BaseAST@antlr@@QAE@XZ)    C:\Users\John Paulo\Documents\Photorealistic Rendering\Prototype\MK-1.1.2\examples\simpleVRML\antlr.lib(BaseAST.obj)
Error   232 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl std::operator==,class std::allocator >(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &)" (__imp_??$?8DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@0@Z) C:\Users\John Paulo\Documents\Photorealistic Rendering\Prototype\MK-1.1.2\examples\simpleVRML\openvrml.lib(browser.obj)
Error   233 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl std::operator==,class std::allocator >(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &)" (__imp_??$?8DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@0@Z) C:\Users\John Paulo\Documents\Photorealistic Rendering\Prototype\MK-1.1.2\examples\simpleVRML\openvrml.lib(node.obj)

this is the captured image of all the errors that I've got when compiling the simpleVRML project(please ignore the GLObjViewer project).
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6bkSbCQZ46zY3BpMjY2NmN2cTA/view?usp=sharing

I hope that someone can help me solve this problem I really need this tool for my study.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems compiling simpleVRML, I solved it by following this 3 video tutorials, specially the last one:

```
Video 1: http://youtu.be/9R52rrlDKpo

Video 2: http://youtu.be/i0igyI6qocY

Video 3: http://youtu.be/hXPFT4dqzu4
```

There they show lines of code you have to modify in order for ARToolKit to compile in newer versions of Visual Studio. Have in mind that ARToolKit is discontinued and it was made to work in Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: Thanks for your help I can build my project without a single error.